# Maven won't run scala tests

Tags: scala, maven

I'm using maven scala test plugin as described [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin). I defined two test classes and put them under `src/test/scala`:

[image]

Tests are looking like the following:

```
class LoginTest extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers with WebBrowser with Eventually with IntegrationPatience {
    ...
}
```

My `pom.xml` contains the following dependencies / configuration:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.44.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn test` I got the message:

```
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:1.0:test (test) @ selenium ---
Discovery starting.
Discovery completed in 30 milliseconds.
Run starting. Expected test count is: 0
DiscoverySuite:
Run completed in 91 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 0
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
No tests were executed.
```

Calling tests from `Intellij` brings a message:

```
0 test class found in package '<default package>'
```

Comment: Use scala-maven-plugin (maven-scala-plugin is deprecated) I'm the author of both. Sorry no idea about your question

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problems 
mvn install discovers test, mvn test does not

Answer (score 1):

I had to make 2 changes for this to work in my case:

1. Change the name of the filereport, remove space: `<filereports>WDFTestSuite.txt</filereports>`
2. Explicitly say not to skip tests: `<skipTests>false</skipTests>`

So the configuration block looks like this:

```
                    <configuration>
                        <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                        <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                        <filereports>WDFTestSuite.txt</filereports>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
```